# Can macros in Notepad++ have "simple" keyboard shortcuts

Tags: macros, keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

I've recorded and saved two macros in Notepad++, giving them `Ctrl+B` and `Ctrl+Shift+B` shortcuts respectively. First doesn't work (does not playback macro), while second is all fine (restart doesn't help).

Can macros in Notepad++ have "simple" keyboard shortcuts, like `Ctrl+B`?

BTW: I'm trying to "emulate" formatting shortcuts (like bold, italics etc.), but for Markdown, not for HTML. That's why Notepad++'s plugins like "[WebEdit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/WebEdit/WebEdit%202.1/)" won't help me here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reworded:

You can save a macro with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> shortcut...

but you can't use the shortcut to same combination to call it back.

It think it's because it seems that key stroke is [already used](http://www.keyxl.com/aaacd5a/43/Notepad-Plus-text-editor-software-keyboard-shortcuts.htm) and your own combination is not overridding the original reserved one.

> Ctrl-B    Go to matching brace

It seems like a bug within notepad++ or not well documented feature.

Comment: If I say: "_I've (...) saved two macros (...) giving them `Ctrl+B` (...) shortcuts (...)_", that means, that I **actually saved it** (notice past tense). [Here](http://oi41.tinypic.com/15qbsp4.jpg) and [here](http://oi39.tinypic.com/ily993.jpg) you have a proofs. Please, don't answer saying, that I can't do something, what I actually did. If Notepad++ finds you trying to use keyboard shortcut, that is actually used, it will simple overwrite it (I think). It only has some problems using new shortcut.

Comment: @trejder CTRL + B is reserved by notepad++ and it's not being overridden as you're suggesting.

Comment: @trejder I am not sure if this is caused because of some language barrier but it's OK, I have reworded the answer for you so you don't think `you can't save` means you actually physically `can't save it`. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Thanks (you've pointed me to a right direction -- see my answer), and sorry, if you get me rude. Now, all is fine, though it still doesn't explain, why people are voting-down or trying to close a normal, valid (as I think) question.

Answer (score 3):

Following `mehow`'s answer I found the solution. `Ctrl+B` shortcut doesn't work for my macro, because it is used with another command.

Going (in Notepad++) to `Settings > Shortcut mapper > Main menu`, locating `Go to matching brace` command and setting its shortcut to `None` solved the problem. From this moment, each press of `Ctrl+B` calls my macro, not that previous command.